variable conditionally declared constexpr according to its initialization expression
I'd like to be able to conditionally declare a variable constexpr, according to properties of  its initializer.
My actual use case is a bit complicated but it can be summarized to:
#include <cmath>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr double create_val(T x)
{
    // some code that can be constant evaluated or not, according to T
}

int main() {

    constexpr_if_possible auto v = create_val(4);

    // w can only be constexpr under certain conditions
    // otherwise it should be at least const
    constexpr_if_possible auto w = create_val(4.0);

    return static_cast<int>(v*w);
}

where constexpr_if_possible would actually mean constexpr when the expression can be constant evaluated, and be const otherwise.
Here is an example to illustrate this:
#include <cmath>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr double create_val(T x)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic_v<T>);
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>)
    {
        // some leggit code in constant expression
        // only an example
        return static_cast<double>(x*x);
    }
    else
    {
        // some not usable code in constant expression
        // only an example
        return std::sqrt(x);
    }
}

int main() {

    // constexpr_if_possible is equivalent to constexpr here
    constexpr auto v = create_val(4);

    // conditions are not met, constexpr_if_possible is equivalent to const
    const auto w = create_val(4.0);

    return static_cast<int>(v*w);
}

clang and msvc would rightfully reject this code with constexpr w due to the use of the non-constexpr function std::sqrt.
(gcc accepts it and optimizes away the computation, probably because it already declares std::sqrt as constexpr).
Live
According to the template argument of create_val, the initialized variable can or cannot be constexpr.
If I were in a template function I could use if constexpr but, perhaps, at the price of code duplication.
Obviously, I could also read all the codes to determine "manually" if constant evaluation is possible but, as seen in my example, when I'll change language standard, I'll have to parse again all my code to see if situation has changed.
Is it possible (and how) to declare v, w conditionally constexpr with respect to their initializer? In pseudo-totally-incorrect code:
constexpr_if_possible auto w = create_val(...);

(thanks to @Jarod42 for having help me to formulate constexpr_if_possible)
I've got the impression that the language syntax cannot allow for this but would there be some workaround?
NB In real use case, my variable type can be anything (fundamental types as well as classes).

"Strangely, gcc accepts it" gcc marks some math functions as constexpr even if it is not in standard (yet).

For integral types, const would do the job.

@Jarod42 That's what I thought was happening, but GCC also accepts https://godbolt.org/z/jv5je67zo and reinterpret_cast is definitely not constexpr.

const might be good enough for non-integral types, compiler would probably optimize it.

reinterpret_cast<double&>(some_double); is noop, gcc might remove it before checking for constexpr. (if you use float instead, gcc refuses the code too).

As I said it's a simplified example, my actual type can be a class (in my use case, it's a std::array). I'm editing the question to make it clearer.

@Jarod42 Oh, I see. I would still expect GCC to diagnose the existence of the reinterpret_cast, regardless of whether it's a noop, but maybe that's ok.

Use MACRO?, #if __cplusplus <= 202302L #define CPP26_CONSTEXPR /*empty or const?*/ #else #define CPP26_CONSTEXPR constexpr #endif.

I dont understand the question. Are you saying that in your not-simplified example you have the same issue with gcc, that it has something constexpr that you want to be not constexpr ? Because apart from that, your code is already doing what you want, no?

...or are you asking how to change main such that the other compilers accept the code?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai Sorry, the remark on gcc added noise to the question. My goal is to have a code that compiles with all the compilers. For a more realistic use case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78676552/21691539: I'd like to declare a std::array constexpr if its initializer can be made a constant expression.

@11638718 quite the opposite: Your CE shows how to make gcc fail, not how to make clang work.

but isnt that the example you wanted to have? And now the quesiton is how to change constexpr auto w = create_val(4.0); so it does infer that create_val(4.0) is not constexpre and hence automagically delcare w as not constexpr? If its not that, then I am still confused

@Jarod42 with const I cannot reuse my value in constant evaluated context. For instance if I declare v as const: constexpr auto z = create_val(static_cast<int>(v));. (Yet I'm surprised to be able to use it as NTTP). Does it mean that it would be always better to declare variables const instead of constexpr?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I'll try to rephrase the question

@Oersted OK, I see. So you probably mean https://godbolt.org/z/qrn4ETfnE?

As I understand, you want a "constexpr_if_possible". It is what const does for integral types (inherited from C++98, when constexpr didn't exist).

@Jarod42 Exactly the wording I needed! but does your comment about const can be transposed to any type?

@11638718 Oh I see, I've got the impression that my comment in the snippet is confusing: it's not the expected behavior. Rephrasing again...

What value does constexpr_if_possible provide? You can't use the result as a constant expression, such as a template parameter. You aren't guaranteeing compile time initialization. Seems equivalent to const?

You want a "constexpr_if_possible".
It is what const does for integral types only (inherited from C++98, when constexpr didn't exist). i.e const int x = 42; is equivalent to constexpr int x = 42; whereas const int y = read_int_from(std::cin); is not constexpr.
const might be good enough for non-integral types, compiler would probably optimize it.
For those types, they couldn't be used as NTTP, but if it is required, then you know you have to use constexpr instead.
C++23 reduces restriction about constexpr functions to allow to use functions which might be marked as constexpr in future (standard), but there are nothing to declare variable as constexpr_if_possible.

Regarding your remark on NTTP, I theoretically agree with you but, practically, CE does not:https://godbolt.org/z/sxshrq7d9. I don't find why in the standard. I don't know if the compilers are wrong. I think that maybe this part of the answer should be reexamined.

A more convoluted example: const integral variable seemed to be accepted in NTTP but const objects of classes cannot be used as CNTTP: https://godbolt.org/z/1sxh3EKxv

In const int y = 42;, y is an integral type (int), so const is equivalent to constexpr (as 42 is a constant expression) (it is not for const int x = argc; as argc is not a constant expression).

I think the right reference si https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Manifestly_constant-evaluated_expressions. Especially initializers of variables with reference type or const-qualified integral or enumeration type, but only if the initializers are constant expressions. So the exact answer would be: for integral type, const does the job (usability in constant evaluated context if the initializer is itself a constant expression). No way to make the variable usable in constant expression otherwise. Do you agree?

To be more specific const int x = initializer is equivalent to constexpr int x = initializer if initializer is a constant expression.

Yes, we agree, with different wording.
